# How to use "open_files_in_new_window" on Windows in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

This question has been asked before but they are all for Mac OS.

Is there a way to get:

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false,
```

to work in the Windows version of Sublime Text 3?

Comment: No there is no option.
to my knowledge

Comment: Darn, @Ahwar If I ever find a solution or plugin. I shall answer this question with the answer! Thanks for commenting at least :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "open_files_in_new_window" does not work in Windows.

But this works for me:

1. Press Windows button and search for Sublime
2. Right click on 'Sublime Text' and open file location
3. Right click and open Properties of the Shortcut
4. Add -a at the end of Target field like this "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -a

-a or --add:    Add folders to the current window (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html)